# pointer that is assigned value in function is blank after returning

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

Making a function for adding a customer record on to a text file.
I have made a function that would trim leading and last spaces off customer name etc, called trimspaces.

the function addrecord is to handle storing of record in file. It gets given 3 parameters (name /address/ phone). Before storing operation function will remove whitespaces using trimspaces function, then combine the 3 strings to one.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //mkdir
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <errno.h> //error number
#include <unistd.h> //access
#include <string.h> //strcat
#include <ctype.h> //isspace
#include <stdlib.h>//malloc

int checkFile();
int makeFile();
int addRecord(char* name, char* addr, char* phon);
int searchRec(int column, char* value);
char* getRec(int recNo);
int getRecNo();
char* trimspaces(char* string,char*ptr);


int addRecord(char* name, char* addr, char* phon){
    printf("\n- starting records addReord function -\n");   
    int success = 0;

    char* namt = trimspaces(name,namt);
    char* addt = trimspaces(addr,addt);
    char* phot = trimspaces(phon,phot);

    //this prints "trimmed words: , , " 
    printf("\n trimmed words: %s, %s, %s",namt,addt,phot);  


    /*
    char*combined1 = strcat(namt,"|");
    char*combined2 = strcat(combined1,addt);
    char*combined3 = strcat(combined2,"|");
    char*combined4 = strcat(combined3,phot);

    printf("\nwords combined: %s",combined4);

    */

    printf("\n- leaving records addrecord function -\n");
    return success;
}



char* trimspaces(char* string,char*ptr){
    printf("\n- entered trimspaces function -");    

    char *str= string;
    int slen = strlen(str); //string length
    int ctfor = 0; //counter forward
    int ctbak = 0; //counter back

    while(isspace(*str)){ str++; ctfor++; }; //count to start of word
    while(*str){str++;}; //go to end

    do{ str--; ctbak++; }while(isspace(*str)); //count from end to end of word

    int cbako = (slen - ctbak) + 1; //counter back reversed
    int wlen = cbako - ctfor; //get word length

    printf("\nstr_len:%d,counter_fore:%d,counter_bak:%d,cbakreversed:%d,wlen:%d",slen,ctfor,ctbak,cbako,wlen);  

    while(*str){ str--; }
    str++;

    while(isspace(*str)){
        str++; 
    }





    char newStr[wlen]; //char pointer gives segmentation fault
    memcpy(newStr,str,wlen);
    printf("\n--%s--",newStr);

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(newStr)+1);
    ptr = newStr;
    printf("\nPTR is : %s",ptr);

    return ptr;
    printf("\n- leaving trimspaces function -");
}


int main(){
    addRecord("kara","19,sams st","993328");

}
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT:
(I want the text between --text-- to be string with leading/end spaces remvoed, and timmed words lines to say - TRIMMED words: kara,19,sams st,993328)

```
- starting records addReord function -

- entered trimspaces function -
str_len:4,counter_fore:0,counter_bak:1,cbakreversed:4,wlen:4
--kara--
PTR is : kara
- entered trimspaces function -
str_len:10,counter_fore:0,counter_bak:1,cbakreversed:10,wlen:10
--19,sams st@--
PTR is : 19,sams st@
- entered trimspaces function -
str_len:6,counter_fore:0,counter_bak:1,cbakreversed:6,wlen:6
@--93328s W
@TR is : 993328s W
 TRIMMED words: , , 
- leaving records addrecord function -
```

Ive met 2 problems in the output of main function. first the printed string at - printf("\n TRIMMED words: %s, %s, %s",namt,addt,phot); 
reads :  TRIMMED words: , ,
Ive tried a number of things but the returned variables are always blank. I wonder if Im using malloc and pointers right.

second problem is

```
--19,sams st@--
PTR is : 19,sams st@
@--93328s W
@TR is : 993328s W
```

I dont know where the @ and Ws come from. When I tested trimspaces function with different values it printed correct results.

I will note here that I used export PS1='\u@\h: ' on terminal for a shorter prompt.

what should I do to get the variables to print values?

Comment: In your calls to `trimspaces`, the arguments `namt`, `addt`, and `phot` are uninitialized. This code has undefined behavior.

Comment: In `ptr = malloc(...); ptr = ...` the value returned from `malloc` is lost. This is a memory leak.

Comment: You create a local variable `newStr[wlen];`. This variable (and its content) disappear after the function returns. And the string that you copy is not NULL-terminated.

Comment: `trimspaces` returns `newStr` (actually a pointer to the first element of `newStr`), which is a local array, which ceases to exist after the function returns. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: On many platforms, `char` is a signed type (i.e. it can have a negative value). Passing a negative value to `isspace` has undefined behavior (unless it's `EOF`). This should be `isspace((unsigned char)*str)`.

Comment: `return ptr;` returns from the function. The following `printf` is dead code.

Comment: Your loops don't handle empty strings correctly.

Comment: If `string` consists of spaces only, your `do`/`while` loop runs off the beginning of the string. Undefined behavior again.

Comment: For strings that contain non-space characters, the `while(*str){ str--; }` loop runs off the beginning of the string anyway. This loop cannot work.

Comment: You fail to *nul-terminate* `newStr` in `memcpy(newStr,str,wlen);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback given Ive modified the code to correct some of the mistakes. this code may not be quite proper and there are still problems(apparently blank inputs strings to trimspaces function gives errors - Im leaving this problem alone and moving on for the moment)

after some digging I found that you need to pass a pointer to a pointer (**) for malloc to work on the variable passed to a different function. still dont understand these principles well but it seems to work. also use strcat on pointer space and char array instead of use of direct = operator.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //mkdir
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <errno.h> //error number
#include <unistd.h> //access
#include <string.h> //strcat
#include <ctype.h> //isspace
#include <stdlib.h>//malloc

int addRecord(char* name, char* addr, char* phon);
void trimspaces(char* string,char**ptr);



int addRecord(char* name, char* addr, char* phon){
    printf("\n- starting records addReord function -\n");   
    int success = 0;

    char* namt = "";
    trimspaces(name,&namt);
    char* addt = "";
    trimspaces(addr,&addt);
    char* phot = "";
    trimspaces(phon,&phot);

    //this prints "trimmed words: , , " 
    printf("\n TRIMMED words: %s, %s, %s",namt,addt,phot);  

    printf("\n- leaving records addrecord function -\n");
    return success;
}



void trimspaces(char* string, char** ptr){
    printf("\n- entered trimspaces function -");    
    //PROBLEMS WITH 0 SIZE OR BLANK INPUT

    char *str= string;
    int slen = strlen(str); //string length
    int ctfor = 0; //counter forward
    int ctbak = 0; //counter back

    while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)){ str++; ctfor++; }; //count to start of word
    while(*str){str++;}; //go to end

    //unsigned char
    do{ str--; ctbak++; }while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)); //count from end to end of word

    int cbako = (slen - ctbak) + 1; //counter back reversed
    int wlen = cbako - ctfor; //get word length

    printf("\nstr_len:%d,counter_fore:%d,counter_bak:%d,cbakreversed:%d,wlen:%d",slen,ctfor,ctbak,cbako,wlen);  

    while(*str){ str--; }
    str++;

    while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)){
        str++; 
    }





    char newStr[wlen+1]; //char pointer gives segmentation fault
    memcpy(newStr,str,wlen); //not null terminated
    newStr[wlen] = '\0';

    printf("\n--%s--",newStr);

    //PASS POINTER TO POINTER for malloc to work / malloc inside another function
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(newStr)+1); //memory


    strcat(*ptr,newStr);    
    printf("\nPTR is : %s",*ptr);


    printf("\n- leaving trimspaces function -");

}


int main(){
    addRecord("   ertsfs  ","  120,Dans st  ","   111 000 222");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to pass `ptr` as argument to `trimspaces` calls.

This works (even if `string` is just whitespaces or empty):

```
char *trimspaces(char *string){
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    char *s = string; //start
    char *e = string + len - 1; //end

    while(s <= e && isspace(*s)) s++;
    while(e >= s && isspace(*e)) e--;

    size_t size = e - s + 1;
    char *ptr = (char*) malloc(size + 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = s[i];
    ptr[i] = '\0';

    return ptr;
}
```

If you encounter any problem with pointers out-of-bound (which I doubt) try this using indexes instead of pointers:

```
char *trimspaces(char *string){
    int len = strlen(string);
    int s = 0; //start
    int e = len - 1; //end

    while(s <= e && isspace(string[s])) s++;
    while(e >= s && isspace(string[e])) e--;

    int size = e - s + 1;
    char *ptr = (char *) malloc(size + 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = string[i + s];
    ptr[i] = '\0';

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Fails on empty strings.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`.

Comment: On empty strings you do `e = string + len - 1`, i.e. `e = string - 1`. This has undefined behavior.

Comment: The `ptr` argument is unused.

Comment: This code passes (signed) chars to `isspace`, which is also undefined behavior.

Comment: Just edited it, now it compare `e` and `s` before calling `isspace`. So if `e = string - 1`, `isspace` is never called, thus everything is ok. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: The problem is in `e = string - 1`, not in `isspace`. The problem is still there.

Comment: Consider that `strlen()` returns a value of type `size_t`.

Comment: He said the strings were about names and adresses, Have ever seen a name or adress 2147483648 characters long? But edited it anyway.

Comment: Have you ever seen a C program get exploited through integer overflows triggered by malicious input?

Comment: there is no probem with pointers out of bound unless they are been used to retrieve they're value. so `e = string - 1` is valid as long as `*e` is never used.

Comment: That's wrong. Forming an invalid pointer is UB in and of itself.

Comment: malicious input?? don't get too dramatic. He's not gonna use it to launch missiles. plus, if going to use it for names and adresses and phone numbers, then it will never exceed the size of an `int`.

Comment: OP might not use it to launch missiles, but they might learn from your answer and assume this is how to handle input correctly in C. IMHO it's better to not write subtly broken code in the first place.

Comment: I still think it's valid.

Comment: well that's just hillarious, I'm telling you that an out-of-bound pointer is valid unless it's beign derefreneced and you giving me this example. `&realarray[-1]`, I don't know if you're aware of that but `realarray[-1]` is deferencing the adress `realarray - 1`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir-- The C Standard states quite clearly (6.5.6/8) that if the result of the addition of a pointer and an integer points to anywhere but the same array object as the pointer, or one past the _end_ of the object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It's not even logical. All pointer arithmetic get evaluated just as regular arithmetic (plus some special rules) without even checking if the result adress belong to this program or not. Problems hapen when the adress is beign used to retrieve the corresponding value, then undefined behaviors occure (sometimes a crash if the adress is already allocated by other programs). Let's not forget that pointers are just normal variables that holds an integer.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir-- you are wrong about this. Read the Standard. It clearly states the rules for pointer arithmetic. Whether you think this is illogical is immaterial. That you may be able to get away with this sort of thing with no immediate consequences does not change the fact that it is UB.